# Magento 2.2 admin order rounding price error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

The amount of my order is 50.688
but in the orders listing view I've got 50.68 instead of 50.69

in my order details I've got 50.69. It's correct

what can I do to make a best rounding in the listing?

The bad price

[image: order listing]

The good price
[image: order details]

Comment: orders listing view ??? please attach screen shot

Comment: I added some screen shots

Comment: have you done anything for rounding price?

Comment: Yes I override \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation

    public function round($price)
    {
        return round($price, 4);
    }